# Set version to latest version including prereleases in Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, version, bundler

How do I specify a version constraint in a Gemfile, such that it always take the latest release including pre-releases of a gem.

Currently the library I work with has the latest stable release `2.0.0`, and the latest pre-release `2.1.0.alpha.pre.171`.

I could set the version constraint to `>=2.1.0.alpha.pre.171` or just `>=2.1.0.a`, as I understand it. But would that also include future pre releases such as `>=2.2.0.alpha.pre.1` or even `>=3.0.0.alpha.pre.1` as well as future stable versions such as `3.0.0`? And would that always resolve to the latest version?

*Disclaimer*:
To not be misunderstood, this is not for any productive dependency management. The idea is to have a demo up an running, which should always include the latest features and as well should crash if the latest pre-release is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very bad idea in a nutshell, but it’s very easy to check:

```
%w|2.1.0.alpha.pre.171
   2.1.0
   2.2.0.alpha.pre.1
   3.0.0.alpha.pre.1|.map(&Gem::Version.method(:new)).sort
#⇒ [
#   [0] #<Gem::Version "2.1.0.alpha.pre.171">,
#   [1] #<Gem::Version "2.1.0">,
#   [2] #<Gem::Version "2.2.0.alpha.pre.1">,
#   [3] #<Gem::Version "3.0.0.alpha.pre.1">
# ]
```

So, yes, `>=` will work for any new release, including `2.1.0`.

Comment: I guess this would also include the latest future stable versions, with a different major number, than the specified pre-release. (I've added an example to the original question.)

Comment: Could you please restate the question? I explicitly put stable `2.1.0` version there to show where it is placed in sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do two things:

1. Specify `>= 2.1.0.alpha.pre.171` in your Gemfile. The important thing here is that the specified constraint is itself a pre-release, which is the only way to make Bundler will pick up that you want pre-releases<sup>1</sup>. All future releases, including pre-releases and major releases, will then be included when Bundler looks for updates.
2. Use an automated tool to regularly update the Gemfile.lock. Any of [Dependabot](https://dependabot.com), [Depfu](https://depfu.io) or [Deppbot](https://deppbot.com) would work. (*Disclosure:* I wrote Dependabot.)

Surprisingly, as of Bundler 1.15.1, there's no option that can be passed to `bundle update` that replicates the behaviour created by (1).

---

1. https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/v1.15.1/lib/bundler/index.rb#L194-L200